# write the result of an c code execution in a txt

Tags: c, printf

I got a code for generate all possible necklaces with a fixed density that i need for a work. The problem is that I'm too noob in c to solve the following question: How can i print the result of this code on to a txt instead of the console? 
when the output is enought big i can't see all the necklaces and obviously i need all. Sorry for my awful writing.

```
/*********************************************************************
* C program to generate fixed density necklaces and Lyndon words.    *
* The algorithm is CAT and is described in the paper by Sawada and   *
* Ruskey "An efficient algorithm for generating necklaces with fixed *
* density."   This program, was obtained from the                           *
* (Combinatorial) Object Server, COS, at http://www.theory.csc.uvic.ca *
* The inputs are n, the length of the string, k, the arity of the           *
* string, and d the density, the number of non-0's in the string.    *
* The program can be modified, translated to other languages, etc.,  *
* so long as proper acknowledgement is given (author and source).    *
* Programmer: Joe Sawada                                             *
**********************************************************************/

/*---------------------------------------------------*/
/* This program generates all k-ary fixed density    */ 
/*      necklaces, Lyndon words or prencklaces       */
/*      with length n and density d in lex order     */ 
/*---------------------------------------------------*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int a[100];
int b[100];
int n,k,d,total;
char type;

void Print(int p) {

    int i,j,next,end,min;

    /* Determine minimum position for next bit */
    next =  (d/p)*a[p] + a[d%p];    
    if (next < n) return;

    /* Determine last bit */
    min = 1;    
    if (type == 'p') min = k-1;
    else if ((next == n) && (d%p != 0)) {
        min =  b[d%p]+1;
        p = d;
    }
    else if ((next == n) && (d%p == 0)) {
        min = b[p];
    }

    /* Determine length of String */
    end = n;
    if (type == 'p') end = n-1; 

    for( b[d]=min; b[d]<k; b[d]++ ) {   
        i = 1;
        /* Test for lyndon words */
        if ( (type == 'l') && (n%a[p] == 0) && (a[p] != n)) {}
        else {  
            for(j=1; j<=end; j++) {
                if (a[i] == j) {
                    printf("%d ",b[i]);
                    i++;
                }
                else printf("0 ");  
            }
            printf("\n"); 
            total++;
        }
        p = d;
    }     
}

void Gen(int t,int p) {

    int i,j,max,tail;

    if (t >= d-1) Print(p);
    else {
        tail = n - (d - t) + 1;
        max = ((t+1)/p)*a[p] + a[(t+1)%p];
        if (max <=tail) {
            a[t+1] = max;
            if ((t+1)%p == 0) b[t+1] = b[p];
            else b[t+1] = b[(t+1)%p];

            Gen(t+1,p);
            for (i=b[t+1] +1; i<k; i++) {
                b[t+1] = i;
                Gen(t+1,t+1);
            }
            tail = max-1;
        }
        for(j=tail; j>=a[t]+1; j--) {
            a[t+1] =  j;
            for (i=1; i<k; i++) {
                b[t+1] =  i;
                Gen(t+1,t+1);
            }
        } 
    }
} 

void Fixed() {

    int i,j;

    /* initialize string */
    for(j=0; j<=d; j++) a[j] = 0;

    if (d == 0) {
        if (type == 'n') {
            for (j=1; j<=n; j++) printf("0 ");
            printf("\n");
            total = 1; 
        }
    } 
    else if (d == 1) {
        for (i=1; i<k; i++) {
            for (j=1; j<n; j++) printf("0 ");
            printf("%d \n",i);
        }
        total = k-1; 
    } 
    else {
        /* For prenecklaces we generate necklaces with */
                /* density n+1 and density d+1 and then ignore */ 
                /* the last bit                                */       
        if (type == 'p') { n++; d++; } 

        a[0] = 0;
        a[d] = n;   
        for(j=n-d+1; j>=(n-1)/d + 1; j--) {
            a[1] = j;
            for (i=1; i<k; i++) {
                b[1] = i;
                Gen(1,1);       
            }
        } 
    }
}

void main() {

    int i,j;

    /* type: 'n' necklace or 'l' Lyndon word or 'p' prenecklace */
    printf("Enter n k d type: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d %c", &n, &k, &d, &type);  

    total = 0;
    Fixed();        
    printf("Total = %d\n",total);  
}
```

i've tried to use `fprintf(....);` instead of `printf(...);` pointing to a file without success

Comment: Explain *without success*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is one problem with your question: You are telling us too much about what your program does and too little about what it doesn't do. We don't need to know about necklaces or any other adornments :), we also don't need the whole source code of your program... that's rather distracting from your actual question. Which appears to be about writing output to a file instead of to the console. Try to limit your explanations and code examples only to that which is relevant with regard to the core question.

Comment: post the program where you have used `fprintf`. and also mention what was the failure i.e. _it didn't create any file_ or _created empty file_ or _whatever it is_.

Comment: My problem it's only that when the number of necklaces generated is huge I can't see it all on the console output even if i scroll up, so because of that I need write the result in a file, or maybe another solution that I don't know. I've wrote all the code just in case someone needed to answer my question

Comment: learn file handling  and write your output into a txt file.

Comment: @SurajeetBharati for example i've declared this: FILE *fp; , at the top of every methot(print() and fixed()) that use printf() I wrote fp = fopen("file.txt", "w"); and finally after every printf() i've wrote fprintf(fp,.....).
I didn't get an error but this doesn't write the same that is written in the console output

Comment: Ok, i've solved my problem. I made a miskate writting  fp = fopen("file.txt", "w") in the print() and fixed() methods, I only need to write this sentence in the main() method. Thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to do this:

1. If you are on Linux you can just `./myprogram 2>&1 | tee output.txt` when you want to execute your program, this allows you to write the output both to console an to the file output.txt.
2. You can use system calls to change the stdout file descriptor from 1 (see:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) to the file descriptor of the file you want to write the output to. To get the file descriptor of the file you want to write output, you use the system call open (see: http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:open), as you can see it will return the file descriptor. Finally you just need to swap the stdout file descriptor with the file file descriptor using the system call dup2 (see: http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2). Dont forget to close the file in the finish using the system call close (see:http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:close)

Note: Since you still require some user interaction on the begin of your program

```
printf("Enter n k d type: ");
scanf("%d %d %d %c", &n, &k, &d, &type);
```

if you choose the second option, you can just swap the file descriptor after that interaction, and in the end when you want to show the result, just swap again.

Comment: I believe the parameters should be from console, but the result itself should be put in file, so why not just use `fprintf`?

Answer (score 0):

Leave first printf and scanf as it is - these are parameters of program (you can get them from file, but I assume that by saying "the result of code" you mean the result of algorithm)

With this in mind, we need to focus on Fixed, Gen and Print functions:

First of all - this amount of global variables you are using is considered bad practice:

- it's harder to analyze the code of functions
- the names of these variables tell us nothing - what's the purpose of n, k, d, a, b?

When you work on this, for writing to file you will need to pass another parameter to every function, which output you want to redirect to file.

So `fopen()` desired file in main (you can prompt user for name of file to save):

```
file = fopen(file_name, "w");
if (!file) {
   /* handle file opening error */
   ...
}
```

Pass file to `Fixed()` and `Print()`, change `printf(...)` to `fprintf(file, ...)` and `fclose()` before leaving `main()`.